# Cypress clearLocalStorage and beforeEach

Tags: javascript, jwt, cypress

I recently started to use Cypress, and I read [here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/clearlocalstorage#Syntax) that `clearLocalstorage()` is automatically executed every time a new test starts.

However, does it get executed before or after `beforeEach` command? I mean, what happens if I have

```
beforeEach(() => {
    cy.viewport(1980, 1024)
    cy.restoreLocalStorage()
})
```

?

I've tried but for now results seems to be unpredictable: sometimes I have the localstorage set, sometimes seems not; however maybe it's my code fault, since I'm working with jwt auth tokens; so I have to be sure on how to manage correctly `cy.restoreLocalStorage()`.

For the records, my code is the following

on a separate file:

```
const username = myUsername
const password = myPassword

//it does a post to obtain a jwt token
Cypress.Commands.add('postToken', () => {
  cy.request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: siteUrl,
    body: {
      identifier: username,
      password: password,
    },
  })
    .its('body')
    .then(res => {
      user = res.user
      cy.setLocalStorage('jwt', res.jwt)
    })
})
```

on main test.js file

```
describe('Cypress', () => {
    before(() => {
        cy.postToken()
        cy.saveLocalStorage()
    })

    beforeEach(() => {
        cy.viewport(1980, 1024)
        cy.restoreLocalStorage()
    })

    describe('Authentication API', () => {
        it('should login', () => {
            cy.getLocalStorage('jwt')
            .should('exist')
            .then(token => {
                console.log('Identity token', token)
            })
        })

        it('should logout', () => {
            cy.getLocalStorage('jwt')
            .should('exist')
            .then(token => {
                cy.clearLocalStorage()
                cy.getLocalStorage('jwt').should('be.null')
            })
        })
    })

    describe('Authentication WEB', () => {
        it('Login', () => {
            // I empty localStorage so I can work in a clean state
            cy.clearLocalStorage().then(() => {
                cy.getLocalStorage('jwt').then(token => {
                    console.log(token)
                })
            })

            cy.visit(siteUrl)
            cy.url().should('contain', 'login')
            cy.get('#username').type(username)
            cy.get('#password').type(password)
            cy.get('#doLoginBtn').click()
    
            /*** this one sometimes has success sometimes fails ***/
            cy.getLocalStorage('jwt').then(token => {
                console.log(token)
            })
            .then(() => {
                cy.url().should('contain', 'logged')
            })
        })            
    })    
})
```

Comment: Why dont you just use `cy.postToken()` in the beforeEach() and not worry about saving and restoring local storage there ?

Comment: @mosaad well its not a bad idea, but main question remains: what runs first, the automatic `clearLocalStorage()` function or the `beforeEach`?

Comment: `clearLocalStorage()` is first, if you want to preserve local storage in between tests just add this
`afterEach(() => {
  cy.saveLocalStorage();
});`